# Chirpy and ASP.NET 4

Tags: javascript, css, visual-studio-2010, add-in, chirpy

Why chirpy v2 (last version) does'nt work on vs2010 ASP.NET 4 but work on vs2010 ASP.NET 3.5 or earlier?

It's site: http://chirpy.codeplex.com

Comment: Could you be a little more specific when saying *not work*? What have you tried, what didn't work, what error did you get, ... present us your problem?

Comment: Worked but occured an error and doesn't nested generated file

Comment: Is it an error with a config, js, css, or coffee file? Need some specifics, and I might be able to help!

Comment: This error occured with all type of files, compressed file created but a refresh needed in solution explorer and compressed file will not be nested within main file. But this problem will not be occurred in ASP.NET 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **[version 2.0.4](https://chirpy.codeplex.com/releases/view/79914)**, which wasn't available when you asked this question.  If you go to the Chirpy codeplex page and click download, you get v2.0.1, which is marked as the recommended release (not sure why).